# c# wants extra Argument when called from python (.net with ironpython)

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, ironpython

I have this in c# (Gameobject is from unity3d)

```
namespace DLLTest
{
    public class buttong : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public GameObject BButtn([ParamDictionary] IDictionary kwargs)
```

This in the python init:

```
engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DLLTest.buttong)));
```

And this in Python:

```
from DLLTest.buttong import BButtn
def BButton(**kwargs):
    BButtn(kwargs)
```

And i keep getting

```
TypeError: expected buttong, got dict
```

When i call it from c# it only wants the dictionary (i think), but from python it demands 2 Arguments a buttong type extra, i wonder why and how to supply a buttong type.

Comment: I'm not sure... but could it be you need to add self ?

Comment: May you add a line of code where you think i should try it. I am not so well with c# since i only use it as interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you method BButtn is not static. so you need to call it with an instance of buttong (or make it static)

try doing

```
from DLLTest import buttong
def BButton(**kwargs):
    b= buttong()
    b.BButtn(kwargs)
```